# Cannot upload github release asset through API

Tags: github-api

I have a github release with no assets yet:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/cljsinfo/api-docs/releases/1260660/assets
[

]
```

But I cannot [upload an asset](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset) to this release:

```
$ curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/edn" --data-binary @cljsdocs-full.edn "https://api.github.com/repos/cljsinfo/api-docs/releases/1260660/assets?name=full.edn&access_token=$(cat my-token)"
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

my api access token has `public_repo` access.  Thanks for any helping on uploading this asset.

Comment: Would it work if you replace `$(cat my-token)` with the actual token (in case of the newline returned by cat is the issue)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're making the POST request to https://api.github.com/repos/cljsinfo/api-docs/releases/1260660/assets which is not the upload URL for the release. It should be https://uploads.github.com/repos/cljsinfo/api-docs/releases/1260660/assets.

See the docs for more info:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset

Answer (score 6):

The asset upload URL is of the form `https://<upload_url>/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id/assets?name=foo.zip`. There are several possible reasons you might get the very unhelpful "Not Found" error:

1. **Wrong release id**. The `:id` field in the URL above is *NOT* the name you gave the release, but a numeric id generated by GitHub (probably a database ID). To get the release ID, you have to call the [releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-assets-for-a-release) and search through the JSON response for a release where the `tag_name` is equal to the name you used. For example, if you named your release `v0.0.3`, search in the JSON for a release with `"tag_name": "v0.0.3"` and use that release's `id` field.
2. **Wrong upload URL**. The URL you use to upload assets is not the same one ou use for all other API calls. To get the right upload URL, you use the same [releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-assets-for-a-release), find your release using `tag_name` a described above, and extract the `upload_url` field from the JSON response. This is Ivan's (accepted) answer.
3. **Missing GitHub access token permissions**. This is the one that tripped me up the worst, as the token I was using *was* able to make API calls to the releases API and get info about my repo, but *NOT* upload assets to that same repo. The "Not Found" error response doesn't hint at this at all. Check the permissions for your token in your [personal access tokens page](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and make sure `repo` and/or `public_repo` are checked, as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for Enterprise flavored GitHub, the upload url isn't the same form as for 'github.com', and you should use the 'upload_url' returned when creating/querying the release:[Get Release API Docs](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.6/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release)

For example here's what's returned from our enterprise github server (slightly munged to protect the guilty):
`"upload_url": "https://git.example.com/api/uploads/repos/example-owner/example-repo/releases/5/assets{?name,label}",`