# How to upload github asset file using CURL

Tags: git, curl, github-api

I want to upload a file on my desktop called 'hello.txt' to my git repository which has a release. How do I do this? I read the git documentation but it says something like :

`POST https://<upload_url>/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id/assets?name`. How to do this in CURL. I did not understand this.

How to post this file as a release asset to my github release? Thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/149329/219423 is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not sure if it accepts that. Was looking for the complete git command so I could modify it according to my needs and understand it too

Comment: In the question, you specifically said that you want to do this using cURL. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yeah but what is this <upload_url>? How to upload a file on my desktop ? If you are aware of how to create a request I want, could you write an answer?

Answer (score 26):

```
curl \
    -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: $(file -b --mime-type $FILE)" \
    --data-binary @$FILE \
    "https://uploads.github.com/repos/hubot/singularity/releases/123/assets?name=$(basename $FILE)"
```

- https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-09-25-releases-api/
- [Cannot upload github release asset through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066239/cannot-upload-github-release-asset-through-api)

Comment: If someone reaches here after trying this for enterprise version of github, you have a different upload url instead of 'uploads.github.com'. The upload url for your particular enterprise version would be returned as a parameter (upload_url) when creating a new release

Answer (score 8):

Extending upon @galeksandrp's answer, here are some issues I encountered

Note that the `--data-binary` option copies the file contents first to RAM, so if you have large files say close to 2048MB i.e. the absolute limit for github releases and if the RAM isn't enough, it fails with `curl: option -d: out of memory`.

The fix for that is to use `-T file path` (without the @).

And also on a side note, if you want to see the upload progress, you need to pipe the output to `cat` such as `curl <...the whole command> | cat`

So the complete command would look like this

```bash
curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Length: <file size in bytes>" \
    -H "Content-Type: $(file -b --mime-type $FILE)" \ #from @galeksandrp's answer
    -T "path/to/large/file.ext" \
    -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \ 
    https://uploads.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo>/releases/<id>/assets?name=<name> | cat
```

***Note:***
An alternate way is to use `gh release upload <tag> <files>... [flags]` instead of curl. ([docs](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_upload))

[`gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli) is GitHub's official command line tool.