# Upload file via GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I want to upload zip file to my repository GitHub.
How can i make this methods API and PHP+CURL? 
I tried to find the description in the documentation, but I did not find how to send the file

Comment: Check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/40216228

Comment: Do you want to add the zip file to your Git repository, or to a release? Here is the documentation for the first case: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file. Adding assets to a release can also be done through the API: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset.