# github actions tag add asset

Tags: github, tags, github-actions

I am creating a tag in a github action like so:

```
  - name: create tag
    uses: actions/github-script@v6.1.0
    with:
      script: |
        github.rest.git.createRef({
          owner: context.repo.owner,
          repo: context.repo.repo,
          ref: 'refs/tags/tag_${{ env.tagname }}',
          sha: context.sha
        })
```

Once the tag is created, I can view it in the list of tags for the repo, and associated to it, there are two 'assets', namely both a zip and tar of the source code. I'd like to know if can also add a meta data text file to the assets. For example, I'd like to include in this meta data file, the name of the person who ran the workflow via workflow_dispatch that created the tag.

Thanks to @rethab for suggesting this API:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/assets#upload-a-release-asset
From it I have taken this code:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://uploads.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/releases/RELEASE_ID/assets
```

However there is no place in the post request for me to put the file I am trying to upload. Where should I put this?

Comment: Try https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/assets#upload-a-release-asset

Comment: @rethab, thanks for pointing me towards the right API. I read the docs you linked to, however I still don't understand how to use the API. Where in the post request do I specify the file I am uploading?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload github asset file using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786539/how-to-upload-github-asset-file-using-curl)